# How can i return to the same page after a POST?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to make a comment on a ticket through a view I have, to do that I have created a comment controller with a post attribute. However, when I have performed my process with the comment controller, I want it to return to the original view where I have all the data about what I want to comment on. But I can not get it and work in any way.
It does not seem to be able to find its way back to the Ticket ID itself.

I've tried this return statement in my controller `return RedirectToAction(nameof(Info));` , but I'm just getting this error message back `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`  `WebApplication20.ViewModel.CommentVM.Ticket.get returned null.`

Here is where the Error occur in my view  `@Model.Ticket.TicketCreated`

Anyone have any idea how I should go about returning to the same view after using my post controller?

**Here are my view**

```
@model WebApplication20.ViewModel.CommentVM



@{

    Layout = "_Dashboard";

    var title = "About Ticket";
}

<html>

<body id="page-top">



    <div class="card mx-auto" style="width: 18rem;">
        <div class="card-header">
            <h4><strong>Ticket Status</strong></h4> Created @Model.Ticket.TicketCreated HERE IS THE ERROR MESSAGE
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
            <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Name:</strong>@Model.Ticket.TicketName </li>
            <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Descripton: </strong> @Model.Ticket.TicketDescription</li>
            <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Priority:</strong> @Model.Ticket.TicketPriority</li>
            <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Type:</strong> @Model.Ticket.TicketType</li>
            <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Status:</strong> @Model.Ticket.TicketStatus</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="card shadow mx-auto m-3" style="width: 42rem;">
        <div class="card-header">
            <h4><strong>Comments</strong></h4>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 p-4">
                <form method="post" asp-controller="Ticket" asp-action="Comments" asp-route-Id="@Model.Ticket_Id" >
                    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Comment.Message" class="control-label"></label>
                        <input type="hidden" asp-for="Comment.Ticket_Id" value="@Model.Comment.Ticket_Id" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Comment.Message" class="text-danger"></span>
                        <textarea asp-for="Comment.Message" rows="5" style="resize:none;" class="form-control"></textarea>
                        <button type="submit" btn btn-sucess>Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

        @*TABLE*@

        <div class="row">

            <!-- Area Chart -->
            <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-7">
                <div class="card shadow mb-4">
                    <!-- Card Header - Dropdown -->
                    <div class="card-header py-3 d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-between">
                        <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">Current Comments</h6>

                    </div>
                    @if (Model.Comments.Count() > 0)
                    {
                        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="width:100%">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>
                                        Message
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        Submitter
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        Created
                                    </th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                
                                @foreach (var comment in Model.Comments)
                                {
                                    <tr>

                                        <td width="10%">
                                            @comment.Message
                                        </td>
                                        <td width="10%">
                                        </td>
                                        <td width="10%">
                                            @comment.Created
                                        </td>



                                    </tr>
                                }
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <h5 class="text-secondary m-1">There are no comments for this ticket yet..</h5>
                    }


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        @*END TABLE*@

    </div>
   
    

    <div class="text-center p-3">
        <a asp-controller="Ticket" asp-route-Id="@Model.Ticket.Ticket_Id" asp-action="Create" class="btn btn-success btn-lg text-white w-30">Edit</a>
        <a asp-controller="Ticket" asp-route-Id="@Model.Ticket.Ticket_Id" asp-action="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg text-white w-30">Delete</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript-->
    <script src="/TemplateInfo/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/TemplateInfo/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Core plugin JavaScript-->
    <script src="/TemplateInfo/vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom scripts for all pages-->
    <script src="/TemplateInfo/js/sb-admin-2.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

**Controllers**
Both my Info controller where my view is, and my comment controller where i make the comment process

```
public IActionResult Info(int id)
        {

            CommentVM t = new CommentVM { Comment = new Comments { Ticket_Id = id } };

            t.Ticket = _db.Tickets.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Ticket_Id == id);
            t.Comments = _db.Commenents.Where(f => f.Ticket_Id == id);
            return View(t);

         }


   [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Comments(CommentVM obj)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {                
                _db.Commenents.Add(obj.Comment);
                _db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Info));

            }

            return View(obj);
        }
```

Comment: ```Object reference not set to an instance of an object``` means your object is null. Then you need to send the Id to your view so you have to use RedirectToAction and pass the Id (Ticket_Id). Example: ```return RedirectToAction("Action", new { id = obj.Ticket_Id });```.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. i Tried to put it like this return RedirectToAction("Info", new { id = obj.Ticket_Id });. unfortunately, it became the same problem again

Comment: Are you able to find the Id in your table/database? It looks like ```t.Ticket = _db.Tickets.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Ticket_Id == id);``` is returning null

Comment: This is going to "fix" your error because it won't return null object to the view.
```t.Ticket = _db.Tickets.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Ticket_Id == id); 
if (t.Ticket == null) {  t.Ticket = new Ticket();}```

Comment: @MatheusDasuke You should turn that into an answer.

Comment: @MatheusDasuke has the correct solution.  Try changing your cshtml.

<input type="hidden" asp-for="Ticket.Ticket_Id" value="@Model.Ticket.Ticket_Id" />

Comment: Thanks for all the good answers, I tested like you mentioned @MatheusDasuke and i kept my input type as it was before. It worked, however, I lost all data on the page. When I checked my URL it said that it went from / Ticket / Info / 10 to / Ticket / Info / 0. So I did not really get the ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Object reference not set to an instance of an object` means your object is null.

Then you need to send the Id to your view so you have to use `RedirectToAction` and pass the Id (Ticket_Id).

Example:

```
CommentVM t = new CommentVM { Comment = new Comments { Ticket_Id = id } };

t.Ticket = _db.Tickets.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Ticket_Id == id);

if (t.Ticket == null)
{
   // if it doesn't find the Id in your database, at least it will return the instantiated object (Id will be 0)
    t.Ticket = new Ticket();
}

t.Comments = _db.Commenents.Where(f => f.Ticket_Id == id);

return RedirectToAction("Info", new { id = obj.Ticket_Id });
```

Answer (score 0):

if it is the same controller instead of redirect you can try this

```
   return Info(obj.Ticket_Id);
```

Comment: This would not utilize the [Post Redirect Get pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) and therefore is not a good idea to do.

Comment: It will not make any difference in the pattern, but will work much faster and keep all info.

Comment: What do you mean it won't make any difference in the pattern? Returning the view without performing a redirect is clearly *not* following the pattern. The URL will end up being the address that was POSTed to, meaning that if the user then bookmarks the page they'll get an error, and if they refresh the page it will reattempt the POST. These are not desirable behaviors, and the reason why the Post Redirect Get pattern should be followed, and you should remove this answer as it promotes a poor practice.